# How to include a web tool based on Node.JS in a Java application?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, javafx, javafx-webengine

I want to develop a Node.JS application **inside** a Java application, in a specific frame.

## What I need to do

I have two existing client applications with user interfaces:

- A Java application, desktop app with several frames
- A web tool developed in HTML/JavaScript with the framework Node.JS

I want to merge those applications in one single Java application. For example the web tool will be embedded in a Java frame of the existing Java application.

Moreover, both apps have to interact. For example, the Java application has to be aware of any change done in the embedded web frame.

Both applications are quite complex, so the goal is to re-use existing sources.

## What I am trying

I know that JavaFX allows the implementation of HTML components in the Java user interface. However, I am struggling with the Node.JS dependencies.

Is it possible to include Node.JS dependencies in the webviewer of JavaFX for example?

If not, is there any mean to do an embbed a web app in a Java app?

Comment: Are you trying to include a javascript webapp's server inside a java app?  You might want to read https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/node_js_and_io_js

Comment: Oh it seems that my comment was not sent the other day... sorry.   Thanks for your link, it is very interesting! If I understood it well, I can develop a NodeJS application like I am used to do, and then launch it with Nashorn API. Then, a webview component will display the web interface in a Java component. Am I right?